# Sound is not working on my computer

Tags: audio, webcam, speakers

I have a Windows 10 (1909) desktop with two audio devices connected: regular stereo speakers through the back panel 3.5mm jack, and a webcam with a microphone.
If I'm playing music over the stereo speakers, when the display turns off, the music keeps playing. But if I'm playing it to the receiver over HDMI, when the display turns off, the sound switches to the stereo speakers. Presumably this is because HDMI carries video and audio and Windows can't turn off only the video part.
So I'd like to find a way to change the power setting controlling display idle off automatically depending on which audio device is active. Is there any way built-in to Windows to do this? If not, a script or something?